# WS Addressing

Tags: terminology, ws-addressing

What is WS Adressing?

Thanks
Sekar

Answer (score 3):

[WS-Addressing or Web Services Addressing is a specification of transport-neutral mechanisms that allow web services to communicate addressing information.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing)